# How to get Attributes in libxml2 and save in stl map for c++?

Tags: c++, libxml2

I want to get the attributes of an xml using libxml2 and save it to a stl map in C++?

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail what you're trying to do? Also, what parsing API in libXML2 are you using?

Comment: I want to get all the attributes per node(s), and save it to a map so that it is easy for me to get all the attributes of the specific node i want. I'm also making class per node and saving it to a list container.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have parsed your XML string/file, and already have a node that you want to map the properties, it should be something like this:

```
xmlNodePtr yournode = ...;
std::map<std::string, std::string> yourmap;

for(xmlAttrPtr attr = yournode->properties; attr != NULL; attr = attr->next)
{
    yourmap[attr->name] = xmlGetProp(yournode, attr->name);
}
```

Of course, the namespaces are not considered in this example. If you are using namespaces, you could try the following instead:

```
yourmap[attr->name] = xmlGetNsProp(yournode, attr->name, attr->ns->href);
```

You should check for `NULL` values thoroughly, of course.